# Convert to a specific style in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle.
I have the following code:

```
convert(varchar,convert(datetime,p.portfolio_date),112)
```

How can I achieve the same in oracle?

**EDIT:**

I have the below code but it is failing:

```
SELECT to_char(convert(datetime,p.portfolio_date),112)
```

Comment: Don't need to tag `tsql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle we use `TO_CHAR` function to convert datetime type to character type. SQL Server style 112 is YYYYMMDD which can be converted to Oracle syntax this way:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(datetime_column,'YYYYMMDD') FROM table;
```